# Eclipse PyDevd remote debugger Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, eclipse, raspberry-pi, pydev, remote-debugging

I have just created a **SSH** connection between my **Raspberry Pi 3 b+** and my computer using WiFi. I have downloaded **Eclipse** and the **PyDev** and **RSE** plugins so I can use Eclipse as IDE for my Python scriptss that I need to run on my Rasp Pi.

Everything works fine, I can create the script in Eclipse and run it in the Rasp Pi using the ssh console.

I want to use the **Remote Debugger** from Eclipse to be able to debug my Python codes from my Rasp Pi. So I have installed pydevd on my Rasp Pi `sudo pip3 install pydevd`, started the **Debug Server** (port: 5678) and write this piece of code on my script so it can be debugged on the server.

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages')
import pydevd;
pydevd.settrace('192.168.7.196',port=5678)
```

When I run the script in my SSH shell it appears this error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/RaspIrradiationproj $ python3 test.py
Could not connect to 192.168.7.196: 5678
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 549, in start_client
    s.connect((host, port))
socket.timeout: timed out
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    pydevd.settrace('192.168.7.196',port=5678)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pydevd.py", line 1314, in settrace
    stop_at_frame,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pydevd.py", line 1363, in _locked_settrace
    debugger.connect(host, port)  # Note: connect can raise error.
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pydevd.py", line 356, in connect
    s = start_client(host, port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 549, in start_client
    s.connect((host, port))
socket.timeout: timed out
```

The only thing I can think off is that mybe the IP address of my host computer is wrong, but using `ipconfig` in the windows cmd I obtain:

```
C:\Users\danie>ipconfig

Configuración IP de Windows


Adaptador de Ethernet Ethernet 2:

   Estado de los medios. . . . . . . . . . . : medios desconectados
   Sufijo DNS específico para la conexión. . :

Adaptador de LAN inalámbrica Conexión de área local* 1:

   Estado de los medios. . . . . . . . . . . : medios desconectados
   Sufijo DNS específico para la conexión. . :

Adaptador de LAN inalámbrica Conexión de área local* 3:

   Estado de los medios. . . . . . . . . . . : medios desconectados
   Sufijo DNS específico para la conexión. . :

Adaptador de LAN inalámbrica Wi-Fi:

   Sufijo DNS específico para la conexión. . :
   Vínculo: dirección IPv6 local. . . : fe80::55a2:974c:7067:886f%17
   Dirección IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.7.196
   Máscara de subred . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.254.0
   Puerta de enlace predeterminada . . . . . : 192.168.6.1

Adaptador de Ethernet Conexión de red Bluetooth:

   Estado de los medios. . . . . . . . . . . : medios desconectados
   Sufijo DNS específico para la conexión. . :
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking for an answer I came up with the solution of disabling the firewall and it worked. So i'ts a matter of the access that are permited in the firewall.